# when input becomes very big, problems occurs in the findConsecutiveOnes Java code, why?

Tags: java, arrays

I was asked to find the number of the largest consecutive 1s in an array.

which means, in [1,0,1,1], the answer should be 2.

I wrote a code and it works well when the input is small array.

```
public int findMaxConsecutiveOnes(int[] nums) {
    if (nums == null) return 0;

    int max = 0;
    int finalMax = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] == 1){
            max += 1;
        } else {
            if (max != 0) finalMax = max;
            max = 0;
        }
        finalMax = Math.max(max, finalMax);
    }
    return finalMax;
}
```

But when you try an array of 2840's 1, it will return 2317. I don't know what is wrong with my code. Can anybody give me a clue?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Why are you setting `finalMax = max` when you hit 0?

Comment: because I want to remember the max value at this time.... Oh! I see, I don't need to do this right? cause my next step is to store the value.... oh...

Comment: Also, size is not likely to be the issue here. Look out for patterns in your input. And it would help if you posted a specific (preferably shorter) example.

Comment: I know where's my fault, but why this will change the answer only when the input is very big??

Comment: if the array contains 17s 1, it will return 17, but if I try 2840s 1, it will return a wrong number....

Comment: Like I said, it's very unlikely the size is the issue. You probably have a long sequence followed by a shorter one.

Answer (score -1):

```
public int findMaxConsecutiveOnes(int[] nums) {
    if (nums == null) return 0;

    int max = 0;
    int finalMax = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] == 1){
            max += 1;
        } else {
            finalMax = Math.max(max, finalMax);
            max = 0;
        }

    }
    finalMax = Math.max(max, finalMax);
    return finalMax;
}
```